How can you get the number of Google reCAPTCHA Enterprise API requests via an API?
The GCP console displays the number of API requests that have been made. For example, in the attached image it shows that 33,202 requests were made in the last day.
Is there an API to call that can get the number of requests?


While the GCP console displays the number of reCAPTCHA Enterprise API requests, there isn’t a dedicated API call to retrieve the specific metric directly. However you can achieve this by using Cloud monitoring API. This monitoring API allows you to access and manage monitoring data on google cloud.
To get the number of requests, you can use the timeseries.list method. An example of how you can make the API call using gcloud cli.

gcloud monitoring time-series list –project=YOUR_PROJECT_ID 
–filter=’metric.type=”[recaptcha.googleapis.com/request_count”](http://recaptcha.googleapis.com/request_count%E2%80%9D)
‘ –interval-start= START_DATE     –interval-end= END_DATE
–aggregation=alignment_period=86400s,count

The response will include the count of requests made for the specified time range. In case, if you need the exact requested count, you can raise  a new Issue Tracker thread describing your issue.
